# Please check proof of Lagrange's theorem

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, proof-verification

I would appreciate it if someone could check this proof of Lagrange's theorem using cosets:

$G$ a group, $H$ a subgroup of $G$, and $C$ a left coset of $H$. We will show $|C|=|H|$.

Take an $x\in C$, and consider $S_1=xH$. Then clearly $|S_1|=|H|$*. Take any element $y\in S_1$, say $y=xh_1$ for some $h_1\in H$. Then
$$yH=\{yh|h\in H\}=\{xh_1h|h\in H\}=^{**}xH$$
So $y\in C$, so $|C|\geq|S_1|=|H|$.

Now consider $S_2=C^{-1}x$, then clearly $|S_2|=|C|$. Also, by the definition of the coset, $S_2\subset H$, so $|C|=|S_2|\leq|H|$

Which proves $|C|=|H|$.

---

*It is clear that $|S_1|\leq |H|$. Now if $xh_1=xh_2$, then by the cancellation law $h_1=h_2$, so the $xh$ are all different, hence $|S_1|\geq |H|$.

**Take any $h\in H$. Then $h_1(h_1^{-1}h)=h$, and since $H$ is a subgroup $h_1^{-1}h\in H$. Also, again because $H$ is a subgroup, $h_1h\in H$ for all $h\in H$. This shows that $h_1H=H$ for $h_1\in H$

---

Based on comments, another version:

Take an $x\in C$, and consider $S_1=xH$. Then clearly $|S_1|=|H|$, and since $S_1=C$, $|C|=|S_1|=|H|$

Comment: Why is it clear that $|S_{1}| = |H|$?

Comment: Also, why can every element of $xH$ be written as $x h_{1} h$ for that fixed $h_{1}$?

Comment: @user46944 Can you take a look at my edit?

Comment: @AndreasCaranti Yes, but isn't that exactly what I'm using to show that $|C|\geq |H|$, so why does that need improvement?

Comment: @AndreasCaranti Oke so is this much shortest version correct then? (at the bottom)

Comment: @AndreasCaranti - any proof of Lagrange's theorem is *tantamount* to a proof that the cosets are the classes of an equivalence relation. One can either argue directly that the cosets are a partition, or one can argue that the relation $x\in yH$ is an equivalence relation and then quote the general fact that equivalence relations induce partitions. IMHO the second method is not inherently better, because the direct proof that the cosets form a partition will always be substantively identical to the proof that $x\in yH$ is an equivalence relation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a lot of good thinking. It is not a proof yet. What you've shown is that all the cosets are the size of $H$, but in order to deduce Lagrange's theorem, you need to show two other things: (1) the distinct cosets are disjoint from each other; (2) they cover $G$. Not unless you convince your audience of these two facts will you have shown that the group is *partitioned* into cosets of equal size.

(Aside: your proof that $|C|=|H|$ is correct, but actually quite a bit longer than it needs to be. Note that $C$, as a left coset, has the form $xH$ for some $x\in G$. Your argument that $|S_1|=|H|$ based on $S_1 = xH$ did not use anything special about $x$, and therefore the same argument applies without change to $C$ in the first place. You were basically done already once you could assert $|S_1|=|H|$! [**Edit:** you've noticed this in your edit!] On the other hand, to prove (1) mentioned above, you will need to argue along the same lines as some of your extras.)

Comment: Thanks for the feedback! I half-forgot about the rest of the proof because I think the rest is not the insightful (at least for me this was the more challenging part). Also, I that in my last edit added the shorter version you mention.

Comment: Yes right on. I noticed the edit right after posting :) IMHO the rest of the proof is equally important (even if for you it was easier) because Lagrange's theorem is a consequence of the picture that the proof draws of what the relationship between $G$ and $H$ looks like: a partition of $G$ into cosets each the size of $H$. This picture is a constant leitmotif in group theory, so all the parts of why we know it's true give us insight that we constantly rely on.

Comment: That's good to know. I'll now also take a look at some other proofs to see what other ways of think about this there are. Thanks again.